# Extend strip_tags to return list of tags being stripped

Tags: php, strip-tags

We have a custom-built CMS for one of our clients, and are using `strip_tags` to prevent them from adding unsafe tags to their templates (i.e. script tags.) We take the initial `$_POST` value and save it as a var, then run `strip_tags` on the var and compare the two. If there are any changes, an error is thrown.

They recently reported that they are getting the error even when not using any tags outside of our whitelist. I've run through the content they're trying to save, and not seeing anything that would cause the error to be thrown.

Is there any way to extend `strip_tags` to return a list of the tags it's stripping?

Basically, this is what we're doing:

```
$init_input = $_POST['template_data'];
$_POST['template_data'] = strip_tags($_POST['template_data'],
  "<p><a><div><sub><sup><ul><li><h1><h2><h3><h4><h5><h6><abbr><strong>
   <address><br><hr><table><tr><b><td><tbody><thead><ol><span><i><em>
   <data-accordion><data-accordion-group><data-accordion-heading>
   <select><accordion><accordion-group><accordion-heading><img>
   <style><head><body><html><meta><option><!doctype>");

//Send an email if there are tags being stripped
if($init_input !== $_POST['template_data']){
   Logger::ErrorLog("Unapproved Markup Submitted Within CMS: $init_input");
}
```

Comment: Do you have a sample of the value they submitted which claimed failure when it should not?

Comment: I've had `strip_tags` strip scientific equations for me in the past.

Comment: @IncredibleHat, yes, but it contains a ton of proprietary content that I can't post here. It's also over 500 lines. There isn't a single instance that I can see of a tag other than the ones in the whitelist.

Comment: HTML comments?  Print both and check here: https://www.diffchecker.com/

Comment: @AbraCadaver - got it in one! There was a comment tag in there. I'm having trouble figuring out how to include that in the `strip_tags` whitelist, since it's not a complete tag. I've tried including `<!-->`, but that doesn't seem to work. Any ideas?

Comment: Unfortunately no _Note:

HTML comments and PHP tags are also stripped. This is hardcoded and can not be changed with allowable_tags._ Maybe strip them from `$init_input` with `str_replace`.